# What is tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.PrefetchDataset?

Tags: tensorflow

I ran into some code that gave data in the form of a `tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.PrefetchDataset`. If I am being honest. I don't really understand how this breaks down past `data`. What does `ops`, `dataset_ops`, and `PrefetchDataset` mean generally, if anything at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be related to [tf.raw_ops.PrefetchDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/raw_ops/PrefetchDataset) :
It seems to be an operation that returns an element asynchronously from prefetched dataset.

For instance if the `object_x` is of type:

```
<PrefetchDataset shapes: ((), ()), types: (tf.string, tf.int64)>
```

It is iterable as in;

```
for string_, int_ in object_x:
    print(string_)
```

However, `PrefetchDataset` object doesn't look to be iterator